# Unable to test in-app billing on some android devices

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to test in-app billing. I have uploaded the app on internal test track and added the testers accounts in licensed testers. From all the accounts I have added in licensed testers list, only one of them is able to test in-app billing successfully. For the rest of the users, they are prompted to enter their credit card info instead of being asked to approve or decline by test card. I don't think I have done anything wrong but still not able to test in-app billing on some devices. Any help is appreciated.

Note: All the testers have installed the app from the internal test track opt-in URL

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of requirements for the Google IAB testing.

Prerequisites:

-AndroidManifest must include "com.android.vending.BILLING" permission.

-APK is built in release mode.

-APK is signed with the release certificate(s).

-APK is uploaded to alpha/beta distribution channel (previously - as a draft)
to the developer console at least once. (takes some time ~2h-24h).
-IAB products are published and their status set to active.

-Test account(s) is added in developer console.

Testing requirements:

-Test APK has the same versionCode as the one uploaded to developer console.

-Test APK is signed with the same certificate(s) as the one uploaded to
dev.console.
-Test account (not developer) - is the main account on the device.

-Test account is opted-in as a tester and it's linked to a valid payment
method.

Comment: Thanks but I've done all the above steps and that is why I am able to test it successfully on one of the testers account but I am not sure why I am unable to test it on rest of the test accounts

Comment: I think you have give application licensing
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777?hl=en

also check this:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test